# how does version control work?

Tags: version-control

how does version control usually work?  does it save diff files as a trail with hashes to validate the trail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different VCS use different approaches. CVS, for example, will create a file on the server for each file which you commit. This is essentially a file in RCS format; CVS is only a wrapper around RCS which runs the RCS commands over many files in a directory subtree (RCS can only work on single files).

The RCS file contains a list of changes (version number, checkin message and how much was changed). After that comes a copy of the current HEAD version. The rest of the files are the diffs between the versions ([long explanation](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/RCS-Format.html)).

This way, CVS can quickly return the HEAD version (which is most often requested) and it can compute the other versions.

CVS doesn't do any validation; if one of your files becomes corrupt, you need a backup. Since CVS is based on RCS, it can't version directories nor can it track renames. CVS and RCS use the standard `diff(1)` command to create the diffs.

[Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (SVN) works similarily but adds versioning of directories and renames. Moreover, SVN uses a better diff algorithm (xdelta) which gives a smaller repository.

For an explanation how [Git](http://git-scm.com/) works, see [here](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/).

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Eric Sinks blog series on version control](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html).

Also, Joel Spolsky wrote [Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com/), that finally made me "get" what distributed source control is all about.

There are more than one ways to skin a cat...

Answer (score 0):

[Darcs](http://darcs.net/) is very different and IMHO more intuitive than other SCMs even distributed ones.
There's an excellent guide for beginners about how it works: [Understanding Darcs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_darcs).